# NavigationController does not open new fragment if it is already associated with bottom navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have a fragment in bottom navigation when try to launch new fragment with same id using navigation controller instead of launching new fragment it redirects me to bottom navigation tab.

here is my code

```
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/splashFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/baseTabsFragment"
        android:name="com.abc.abc.fragment.BaseTabsFragment"
        android:label="BaseTabsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_common_tabs">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_to_baseFragment"
            app:destination="@id/baseTabsFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="false" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

And code to navigate.

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_to_baseFragment)
```

Here is a link for more details on this

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/262076827

Update: I want to avoid the code duplication. I will have same fragments with same actions but different id's looking for a better way to do it.

Comment: @ianhanniballake any idea about this?

Comment: AFAIK The back stack shouldn't have duplicate fragment ids; so you'd have a unique fragment id for each one

Comment: but this will lead to code duplication. I will have same fragments with same actions but different id's looking for a better way to do it

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you want to navigate to the same fragment and fragment does not refresh.
If you use navigation component in visual interface you need to pull an arrow from your `baseFragment` onto `baseFragment` again, with this you will see an arrow like self pointed. If you don't use visual just paste below code and it will be created.

```
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_to_BaseFragment"
            app:destination="@id/baseTabsFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/baseTabsFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

We are using this way because if we want system to navigate, it needs different location then previous, as long as we using same fragment we need to pop the old one.

Comment: didn't work still redirects to fragment in bottom navigation instead of opening new

Comment: Now i understand, what you want is not achievable. Because when you describe the destination `app:destination="@id/baseTabsFragment"` of course it will go there which you specified to one of your `bottomNav` item with an id `android:id="@+id/baseTabsFragment"`. It's expected behavior, `id` is unique. So if you want to use same fragment xml on both fragments, just create a xml then include from it to prevent code dublications. And of course you will create an another fragment to hold your second page content with a different `id`, so you can navigate.

Comment: there is not include option for this.

Answer (score 0):

It happened due to bottom menu. In this case you need to call programmatically to click on that bottom button.

Replace

findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_to_baseFragment)

to

navController.navigate(
R.id.base_graph, null,
NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(navController.graph.startDestinationId, true).build()
)

Comment: I don't want to click programatically bottom button my question is not related to this